# Proof that every path in U is homotopic

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, path-connected, loop-spaces

Let $U$ a connected space and given $x,y,x',y'$ four points $\in U $ and it says that every statement implies the other :

> > 1) Every path ( in $U$ ) from $x \longrightarrow y $ is homotopic in $U$
> >
> > 2) Every path ( in $U$ ) from $x' \longrightarrow y' $ is homotopic in $U$
> >
> > 3) Every loop ( in $U$ ) is homotopic in $U$

Here is what I did , 
Two continuous paths $\gamma_{1}$ and $\gamma_{2} $ are path-homotopic if :

$\forall t \in [0,1]\quad f(t,0) = \gamma_0(t)\text{ and } f(t,1) = \gamma_1(t)$ ; ( $f$ continuous function defined for $[0,1]$)

in other words :

$\gamma_0(0) = \gamma_1(0) = x \text { and } \gamma_0(1) = \gamma_1(1) = y$

but it didn't prove anything , the only thing I know for sure is if the three conditions are true then $U$ is simply connected .

Any help would be a lot appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: How can you extend/modify a path from $x'$ to $y'$ into a path from $x$ to $y$ so that you could apply (1) to prove (2)?

Comment: @TokenToucan: there isn’t necessarily a path from $x’$ to $x$ because we only know connectedness of $U$, not path connectedness.

Comment: @Clayton $U$ has to be path connected. Being only connected is not enough. A counterexample is the topologist's sine curve "glued" with a sphere (instead of a point).

Comment: @TokenToucan It is what a homotopy does ? We saw this in our online classes .. I'm a bit lost

Comment: @freakish: be that as it may, the statement doesn’t include path connectedness, only that $U$ is connected.

Comment: Are the four points $x,y,x',y'$ arbitrary or unique? If they are arbitrary, then statement one means "choose two point arbitrarily, then all path between them are homotopic" which implies "there must exist a path between the two point that we choose arbitrarily..", Because, if there's no paths, there is no homotopies. that's why I wonder if those points are arbitrary. But anyway, it's problem about language somehow, and I'm not a native english speaker, so...forgive me if my thought sounds ridiculous... @Simba27

Comment: Hello @Kevin.S yes we can choose the four arbitrary , they're not unique. (Don't worry I'm canadian, maybe that's why there is a confusion in what you read my bad.)

Comment: @Simba27 Now, if assume statement 1) is true, the space is immediately path connected I think, because for any two arbitrary fixed points, all paths between them are homotopic. If not path connected, then as we choose two points arbitrarily, there's no condition to ensure the path between them exists, and therefore no path homotopy, contradicts the assumption that statement 1) is true. But again... I'm not sure.

Comment: @Simba27 However, if my last comment is correct, the second statement doesn't even have to exist in the question, because $x',y'$ belongs to "any two points"... But if the four points are unique, then it makes sense to have such three statments but now we can find lots of counterexamples to disprove it. So, it's still weird. Without path-connectedness, these statement will be far from the truth, So I still think there is something missed in the context of the question......(For instance, the context of that online lesson, were they talking about simply connected spaces or something else...)

Comment: @Kevin.S I just rewinded the video this is what he says : "if one of them is true then they're all true , and what can we say about U  what does it implies ?" So I think that we should take for granted that one of them is true and prove the others ... And is my last statement correct : If they're all true then U is a simply connected space ?

Comment: The third condition implies all loops are homotopic to a constant loop, but in the statement that you have written, you have a connected topological space $U$ and four points labeled $x$, $y$, $x’$, and $y’$. These are arbitrary points, but they are fixed (similar to the statement “Let $n\in \Bbb N$ and...”). However, as freakish already pointed out, the statement is false unless you have miswrote it (you *need* a path-connected topological space $U$, which is strictly stronger than only requiring connectedness).

Comment: @Kevin.S the condition 1 is not "for any points". Those 4 points are fixed. Otherwise condition 1 and 2 would be the same. And neither condition implies that $U$ is path connected. For example consider two point space and set $x=y=x'=y'$.

Comment: @Kevin.S Also the statement "all paths between $x$ and $y$ are homotopic" **does not** imply that there exists a path between $x$ and $y$. The statement is vacously true in that case. And besides even if that was the case, that there are paths between $x, y$ and paths between $x',y'$, then the statement is still false if $U$ is not path connected. That's because we need paths between $x,x'$ and $y,y'$ in order to pass from one homotopy to the other.

Comment: @Simba27 none of these conditions implies that $U$ is simply connected. That's because simply connected means: path connected + all loops are contractible. And none of the conditions implies $U$ is path connected. The simpliest counterexample is $U=\{a,b\}$ the two point discrete space. It satisfies all conditions (regardless of the choice of $x,x',y,y'$) but it is not path connected, so it is not simply connected. Since you talk about $U$ being simply connected I'm pretty sure at this point that the assumption should be "$U$ is path connected" instead of "$U$ is connected".

Comment: @freakish Yeah I would agree with you, but if the four points are equal, then there still exists path but its just constant and in that cases the statement still holds. Also, I said that the implication for simply connected holds if we can obtain the path-connectedness. However, I don't agree with you about the "for any two points" part, those points are fixed but they're not unique, if it holds for arbitrary points then it holds for all point, that's what see from the statement, Well, probably because I missed some important part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all under the assumption that $U$ is only connected these are not equivalent.

Consider $U=T\cup S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ where $T=\{(x,\sin(1/x))\ |\ x>0\}$ is [the topologists's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve) and $S=\{v\in\mathbb{R}^2\ |\ \lVert (-1,0)-v\rVert=1\}$ is the sphere around $(-1,0)$ of radius $1$. This space $U$ is connected, but not path connected. Actually $S$ and $T$ are the only two path components of $U$. Now if I choose $x,y\in T$ then every path $x\to y$ is homotopic, because $T$ is contractible. On the other hand not every path $x'\to y'$ is homotopic when $x',y'\in S$. And so conditions (1) and (2) can be true or false depending on the choice of $x,y,x',y'$. Note that $x,y,x',y'$ here are fixed, chosen before those conditions are stated. Otherwise conditions (1) and (2) would be the same.

---

However these conditions are equivalent if $U$ satisfies stronger condition: being path connected.

With that we can generalize all of those conditions. First some notation. For $x,y\in U$ let $P(x,y)$ be the set of all paths from $x$ to $y$. Let $H(x,y)=P(x,y)/\sim$ be the quotient under "being homotopic" relationship. Then we have:

> **Lemma.** If $U$ is path connected then for any $x,y,x',y'$ there exists a bijection $H(x,y)\to H(x',y')$. In particular all paths $x\to y$ are homotopic if and only if all paths $x'\to y'$ are homotopic.

*Proof.* Since $U$ is path connected then let $\lambda,\beta:I\to U$ be paths such that $\lambda(0)=x$, $\lambda(1)=x'$, $\beta(0)=y$, $\beta(1)=y'$.

Recall that if $f:I\to U$ is a path then $f^{-1}:I\to U$ is the path defined by $f^{-1}(t)=f(1-t)$. And so it is the path in the other direction.

Also if $f,g:I\to U$ are two paths such that $f(1)=g(0)$ then by $f*g$ I will denote [the path composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(topology)#Path_composition) of $f$ and $g$.

Now define

$$P:P(x,y)\to P(x',y')$$
$$P(\alpha)=\lambda^{-1}*\alpha*\beta$$

I leave as an exercise that $P$ is a well defined function. Note that formally there should be brackets here, because "$*$" is not associative. However it is associative under homotopy and so it doesn't really matter. For full correctness you can put brackets however you want, e.g. $\lambda^{-1}*(\alpha*\beta)$.

Unfortunately $P$ is almost never a bijection. However it does induce a bijection on homotopy classes. How do we show that? Well, the inverse is induced by $G(\delta)=\lambda*\delta*\beta^{-1}$ and so all we need to show is that there exists a homotopy

$$\lambda*\lambda^{-1}*\alpha *\beta*\beta^{-1}\simeq\alpha$$

And this is a consequence of the following three facts:

1. "$*$" is associative under homotopy, i.e. $f*(g*h)\simeq (f*g)*h$
2. $f*f^{-1}\simeq c$ and $f^{-1}*f\simeq c'$ where $c,c'$ are constant maps at appropriate points
3. if $c,c'$ are constant maps (at appropriate points) then $c*f\simeq f$ and $f*c'\simeq f$

Can you complete the proof?